# Дана строка. Подсчитать количество букв k в последнем ее слове.Не знаю,как поставить считывание к

Tags: c, массивы, строки

```
#define SIZE 1000
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int poclednya (int k, char string[SIZE]) {
    char ch;
    int i;
    ch=0;
    while(ch!=*"\n")
    k=0;
    for(i=0;string[i]!=*"\n";i--){
       if(string[i]==*"k"){k--;}
    }
    return k;
}

#include <stdio.h>  
#include <coniow.h> 
#define SIZE 1000   // Максимальный размер строки
#define ESC 27
int main(void) {
    char str[SIZE];
    int k;
    void poclednya(int,char*);
    do {
        clrscr();
        printf("Исходная строка\n");    
        scanf("%c\n", &str ); 
        poclednya(k,str);
        printf ("Кол-во букв к в последнем слове %d",k);
        printf("\nВыход - Esc, продолжение - любая клавиша\n");
    } while(getch()!=ESC);
} //End main
```

И проблема с вводом,когда водил буквы или числа,зависал

Answer (score 1):

Я бы делал примерно так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SIZE 1000

int k_in(const char * str, char k)
{
    int count = 0;
    const char * c = str + strlen(str) - 1;  // Последний символ
    while(c != str && isspace(*c)) --c;      // Проходим последние пробелы
    while(c >= str && !isspace(*c))
        if (*c-- == k) ++count;
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    char str[SIZE];
    for(;;)
    {
        printf("Введите строку (ENTER для выхода): ");
        fgets(str,SIZE,stdin);
        if (strlen(str) == 1) break;
        printf ("Кол-во букв k в последнем слове - %d\n",k_in(str,'k'));
    };
} //End main
```

Comment: а как передать на вывод,у меня с этим проблема,если делать файл вывода,не знаю как отправлять

Comment: В смысле? Надо результаты в файл записать или что?

Comment: по проге посмотри,я из одной части в другую слабо представляю,как передавать,плохо обучили и я теперь маюсь пытаюсь понять,как между процессом вывода и подсчета прототип использовать

Comment: Ну, раз уж мед - так ложкой, и просьба помочь заканчивается "разберись, что я не понимаю, и сделай" :), то, думаю, *вам* нужно обратиться совсем в другое место. И научитесь для начала ясно излагать свои мысли - потому что я не понимаю, что вы от меня хотите.